# How to select from a specific table where one column contains values seperated with comas [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to select all rows from table where column_x contains specific value. Although those values are separated with comas and I need to split them at first and check if the first value after splitting contains the string which I'm looking for.

Comment: Either use FIND_IN_SET() or (the best way) normalize your data.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a string!

Comment: Ok, guys, I found the solution:
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(`mycolumn`, ",", 1) LIKE '%myvalue%'